# Getting values from my DataGridView to show on another form - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Basically, when I click on the cell, I want to be able to get everything on that row to show up in another form.

I have this code on my Show Form:

```
 public partial class showTask : Form
{
    public string TaskID, TaskName, TaskDescription, TaskTimeAndDateCompletion;
    public int TaskPriority;

    public showTask()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowTaskChosen()
    {
        showTaskIDRtb.Text = TaskID;
        showTaskNameRtb.Text = TaskName;
        showTaskDescRtb.Text = TaskDescription;
        showTaskPriorityRtb.Text = Convert.ToString(TaskPriority);
        showTaskTimeAndCompletionDate.Text = TaskTimeAndDateCompletion;
    }

}
```

And on my DataGridView named tasksViewerDGV in my mainPage Form, I have this to try and get the values to show on another form:

```
private void tasksViewerDGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int column = e.ColumnIndex;
        int row = e.RowIndex;

        DataGridView ShowTask = sender as DataGridView;
        if (ShowTask == null)
            return; //If the cell is null, then just return without sending any information

        var cell = ShowTask[column, row];

        if (cell != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow rows = cell.OwningRow; //Which ever cell is clicked, it gets the row of that cell
            showTask displayTask = new showTask();

            displayTask.TaskID = rows.Cells["taskID"].Value.ToString();
            displayTask.TaskName = rows.Cells["taskName"].Value.ToString();
            displayTask.TaskDescription = rows.Cells["taskDescription"].Value.ToString();
            displayTask.TaskPriority = Convert.ToInt32(rows.Cells["taskPriority"].Value.ToString());
            displayTask.TaskTimeAndDateCompletion = rows.Cells["taskTimeAndDateCompletion"].Value.ToString();


            displayTask.ShowDialog();
            displayTask.ShowTaskChosen();
        }
    }
```

The problems are these: `var cell = ShowTask[column, row];` as I get the IndexOutOfRange Exception. Furthermore, when debugging it say's -1 on 'row' variable. Finally, it takes me ages to trigger the event, sometimes I ave to press on the cell title multiple times for it to work. I have no clue what is going on, any light that could come my way would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Kieran

Comment: In which method do you have the code above?

Comment: @Steve I have updated my code above, does that answer your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        string value =  dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but get the same problem unfortunately. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[CellContentClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event docs says:

> This event occurs when the cell content is clicked

But *cell content* means just exactly the content of the cell and not some empty space in the cell. In that case you don't get the event fired.

In your context I would use `CellMouseClick`.

However this event is raised also in case you click the row or column headers of the grid. And for these cases the row or column index is -1.

You should have some kind of protection around these *invalid* values for row and column before trying to use them to find your grid cell.

```
private void dgv_CellClickMouse(object sender, 
                                DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    int column = e.ColumnIndex;
    int row = e.RowIndex;

    if(column == -1 || row == -1)
    {
        // for debug purpose...
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid row/column");
        return;
    }

    DataGridViewCell cell = dgv[column, row];

    if (cell != null)
    {

       ...... 
    }
}
```